# samsung geofence error 1000

Tags: samsung

I keep getting a geofence error 1000...How can I fix this error? I looked it up and tried some of the ways it says to fix it but it hasn't fixed. Is there a way to fix it and without resetting my phone?

Comment: Similar Thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19082482/error-adding-geofences-in-android-status-code-1000

Answer (score 1):

**To fix it:**

1. Settings -> Location -> Mode
2. Choose "Device only (Use GPS to determine your location)"
3. Choose any other option to get the popup (e.g. "High accuracy (Use GPS,
   Wi-Fi and mobile networks to determine location")
4. dialog ""Use Google' location services" is shown
5. choose "Agree"

Please refer below thread to know more.

[Geofence Error code 1000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19082482/error-adding-geofences-in-android-status-code-1000/%22Geofence%20Error%20code%201000%22)